# print unique-rows in a matrix

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to solve this question with the help of map. I am new to Map but I am not sure whether my logic for map can be extend to string ?

```
`void findUniqueRows(int M[R][C])

map<int,string> m;
for(int i=0;i<R;i++)
{  
    string str="";
    for(int j=0;j<C;j++)
         str+=M[i][j];
         m.insert(i,str);
     `}

for (std::map<int,string>::iterator it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it)
std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
```

}'

Basically I am trying to create map  with int as row no and string as concatenation of all array elements of that row.
Now for the next row , the same thing happen but if current string matches with existing string in a map , then it wont be inserted. Hence my map would contain unique rows .
Am i correct ?

Comment: This statement str+=M[i][j]; does not make sense provided that M is an array of integers.

Comment: Ok any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your approach is not correct. A `std::map` does not care what about the contents of the second item of the key/value pairs it stores. It only looks at the first item. If it already exists in the map, then subsequent `insert()`s with the same key will not change the map. So in:

```
for (int j=0; j < C; j++) {
    str += M[i][j];
    m.insert(i, str);
}
```

When `j == 0`, the call to `insert()` will succeed, but any subsequent call in that loop will not do anything.

Using a map is not helping you for this problem at all, unless your input arrays are huge and you need to have an algorithm that is faster than O(R²). I would just keep it simple and use the following approach:

```
for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    bool duplicate = false;

    // Check if we have seen this row before
    for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
        // Are the contents of row i equal to those of row j?
        if (memcmp(M[i], M[j], C * sizeof **M)) {
            duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If not, print it
    if (!duplicate) {
        for (int k = 0; k < C; k++)
            std::cout << M[i][k] << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

If you do want to use a map-like approach, you should use a `std::set` instead. Here is a possible example:

```
// Function to compare two rows
auto compare_row = [](int *a, int  *b){
    return memcmp(a, b, C * sizeof *a) < 0;
};

// A set that stores pointers to rows, using the above comparison function
std::set<int *, decltype(compare_row)> myset(compare_row);

// Insert all rows into the set
for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    myset.insert(M[i]);

// Print contents of the set
for (auto &&row: myset) {
    for (int k = 0; k < C; k++)
        std::cout << row[k] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The above example just stores pointers to the original array, so it is quite space efficient. Note that the set is now ordered based on the comparison function, so the result is not necessarily in the same order as the input array. To keep it in the same order, you need to check the results of the `insert()` call and only print when the insertion succeeded:

```
for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
    if (myset.insert(M[i]).second) {
        // print row i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach with using `std::map` can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    const size_t M = 5;
    const size_t N = 6;
    int a[M][N] = 
    {
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    auto comp = []( const int ( *a )[N], const int ( *b )[N] )
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare( 
            std::begin( *a ), std::end( *a ), 
            std::begin( *b ), std::end( *b ) );
    };

    std::map<const int(*)[N], size_t, decltype( comp )> m( comp );

    for ( const int ( *row )[N] = a; row != a + M; ++row )
    {
        ++m[row];
    }

    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        if ( p.second == 1 )
        {
            std::cout << '[' 
                      << std::distance( std::cbegin( a ), p.first ) 
                      << "]: ";
            for ( int x : *p.first ) std::cout << x << ' ';
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
[2]: 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Indeed the row with index equal to 2 is a unique row.